# Removing finite index condition for a problem on coset counting

Tags: group-theory

I was reviewing group theory on my own and tried the following problem on the cosets and counting section of the group theory chapter of Hungerford’s algebra:

Let $H,K,N$ be subgroups of a group $G$ such that $H<K$, $H\cap N = K \cap N$, and $HN=KN$.
Show that $H=K$.

The solution is straightforward if $G$ is finite.
Assuming finiteness of $[H:H\cap N]$, we quickly obtain $[H:H\cap N ] = [K:H] [H:H\cap N]$ via the correspondence of the cosets of $H$ in $H \cap N$ and the cosets of $N $ of the form $kN$, with $k$ in $K$. This immediately gives the desired result $[K:H]=1$.

However, the question was phrased in such a way that no finiteness conditions on the indices or the subgroups were provided. What approach would prove the result in general?

Comment: Do you know the modular law?

Comment: Is this $K \vee (H \cap N) = H \cap (K \vee N)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to do this directly. Let $g \in K$. Then $g \in HN$ so $g=hn$ with $h\in H$, $n \in N$. Since $H \le K$ this gives $n=gh^{-1} \in K \cap N = H \cap N$ so $g \in H$.

Answer (score 2):

Derek's answer is of course correct. Another way to prove it invokes the modular law, which is useful in a variety of contexts.

Recall that the modular law is that if $A\leq B$ then $A(B\cap C)=B\cap AC$. Since $H\leq K$ we have
$$H=H(H\cap N)=H(K\cap N)=K\cap HN=K\cap KN=K.$$

Note that the result is not true if we drop the assumption $H\leq K$.